# AWS JS SDK: How do I access GameLift data from a subaccount / another role using the root IAM account?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I'm not too familiar with the terms, so please bear with me.

I'm working on a CMS site using react. We've already got logon via AWS Cognito in place, and we used to have a page that displays GameFleet data.

However, the Aliases and Fleets have been moved to a subaccount:
[image]
[image]

And as such the GameFleet page is empty.

I've initially overcome this problem by creating an IdentityPool (and roles) for the DevRole subaccount, as the CMS retrieves the GameFleet data via the following code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    AWS.config.region = REGION;
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: IDENTITY_POOL_ID // <--- Changed this to new IdentityPoolId
    });
    
    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
    });

    await this.requestGameLiftData();
};

requestGameLiftData = async () => {
    const gamelift = new AWS.GameLift();
    try {
        const aliasData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            gamelift.listAliases({}, function(err, data) {
                if (err) { reject("Aliases failed");}
                else { resolve(data); }
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

But the problem now is that there is a new subaccount, one I don't have access to, and I can foresee that new subaccounts might be created which won't have the necessary IdentityPoolId required for my approach.

I've been told accessing the subaccount GameLift data from the root account should be possible, but I'm not sure how. I've been looking at the IAM page under the main account, but there doesn't seem to be anything there that could point to the subaccounts.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AWS Assume roles functionality here using which your primary account can assume role of secondary account and get temporary credentials of sub-account which can be used to pull the data from sub-account from primary account.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html